# Python 3 - Merging a variable number of lists into one

Tags: python, list

The code below, results in a variable number of (lines) lists.:

```
BoM = sock.execute(dbname,uid,pwd,'mrp.bom.line','search',[('bom_id','=',Pname)])
for BoMs in BoM:
    RAWnames = sock.execute(dbname,uid,pwd,'mrp.bom.line','read',BoMs)
    RAWnames = RAWnames[0]
    LdM = RAWnames['product_id'][1], RAWnames['product_qty'], RAWnames['x_studio_custo_unitrio']
    BoM = list(LdM)
    print (BoM)
```

Like this one:

```
['Material 1', 1.0, 1.0]
['Material 2', 2.0, 2.0]
['Material 3', 3.0, 3.0]
['Material 2', 2.0, 2.0]
['Material 3', 3.0, 3.0]
['Material 4', 4.0, 4.0]
```

I need to merge these lists into one, so the result would be like below:

```
[['Material 1', 1.0, 1.0],
['Material 2', 2.0, 2.0],
['Material 3', 3.0, 3.0],
['Material 2', 2.0, 2.0],
['Material 3', 3.0, 3.0],
['Material 4', 4.0, 4.0]]
```

How can i achieve this? Is this possible?
Somehow i keep thinking that this should be easy, but i can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Comment: Your "variable number of lists" is surely a _structure_ of lists (e.g., a list or dict of lists), even if it's generated programmatically? What's stopping you simply iterating over that structure and `append()`ing, or `itertools.chain.from_iterable()` or [list comprehensions](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python), or any of a number of other methods. On SO we generally expect _an attempt at a solution_ and, wish respect, there are many basic ways to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a list and append each record into it.

```
records = []

BoM = sock.execute(dbname,uid,pwd,'mrp.bom.line','search',[('bom_id','=',Pname)])
for BoMs in BoM:
    RAWnames = sock.execute(dbname,uid,pwd,'mrp.bom.line','read',BoMs)
    RAWnames = RAWnames[0]
    LdM = RAWnames['product_id'][1], RAWnames['product_qty'], RAWnames['x_studio_custo_unitrio']
    BoM = list(LdM)

    records.append(BoM)

print(records)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. This way i get two lists: [['Material 1', 1.0, 1.0], ['Material 2', 2.0, 2.0], ['Material 3', 3.0, 3.0]]
[['Material 2', 2.0, 2.0], ['Material 3', 3.0, 3.0], ['Material 4', 4.0, 4.0]]

Comment: I was in a nested loop that looped two times. That's why i was getting two lists. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = ['Material 1', 1.0, 1.0]
list2 = ['Material 2', 2.0, 2.0]
list3 = ['Material 3', 3.0, 3.0]
list4 = ['Material 2', 2.0, 2.0]
list5 = ['Material 3', 3.0, 3.0]
list6 = ['Material 4', 4.0, 4.0]

mergedList = []

mergedList.append(list1)
mergedList.append(list2)
mergedList.append(list3)
mergedList.append(list4)
mergedList.append(list5)
mergedList.append(list6)

print(mergedList)
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out. But the problem is that the result lists are variable. I can have 6 lists or 100.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mergedList = [list1, list2, list2, list3, list4, list5, list6]
```